# What is this annoying flashing triangle at the top of my home screen?

Tags: widget

At the top edge of the home screen (status bar?), next to signal strength etc. is an annoying triangle shaped flashing widget.  What is it, and how do I get rid of it?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some context by taking a screenshot (hold Power + Volume Down) of your display when this icon is showing. Some phones display up and down triangles in the status bar to indicate data transfer over WiFi and cellular.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the mobile device's screen it can be one of two:

1. indication of roaming
2. notification from one of the apps that you can see by pulling the list down from the bottom

Hope that helps!